# Searching for a Kohana Beginner's Tutorial for PHP

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana

I am going to try to build a PHP website using a framework for the first time, and after some research here and there, I've decided to try to use **[Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org)**

I downloaded the source from their website, and ran the downloaded stuff on my web server, and was then greeted with a 'Welcome to Kohana!' page, and nothing more...

I've tried to find some beginner tutorials on the web as regard this particular framework, but to my surprise, came up with almost nothing (*only [this one](http://lee.hambley.name/kohana-tutorial), but it's not a great deal of help*)

I am not new to PHP and neither am I new to the MVC concept, but I am very new to PHP Frameworks...so can anyone **point me to a Kohana tutorial somewhere on the web that will help me get started in building my website using this framework, from scratch ?**

P.S. As I said, I want a *beginners* tutorial as regarding this case.

**[UPDATE]**

I am currently reading the [Official Guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/install)...we'll see how that goes.

Comment: +1 .. Thank you ... coming at it today after working mostly with CI.

Comment: The main problem in Kohana official website is the absence of commonly regarded tutorial in many other frameworks such as CakePHP and CodeIgniter "The blog tutorial".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The "Kohana Tutorial" pages are pants. Not so much for their content, but for the fact that they have a pretty damn unorganised wordpress blog and finding useful info isn't exactly made easy. What they need is a post/page at <strike>http://learn.kohanaphp.com</strike> that lists the most important tutorials, rather than forcing you to wade through the whole blog.

Anyway, rant over, I'd start here:

http://zacklive.com/hello-world-tutorial-for-kohana/15/

Then:

<strike>http://learn.kohanaphp.com/2008/03/26/blog-tutorial-1/</strike>

<strike>http://learn.kohanaphp.com/2008/03/28/blog-tutorial-part-2/</strike>

Other articles of interest:

http://www.ninjapenguin.co.uk/blog/2008/06/21/kohana-pagination-tutorial/

<strike>http://learn.kohanaphp.com/2008/04/25/using-auto_modeler-to-write-quicker-code/</strike>

http://www.ninjapenguin.co.uk/blog/2008/06/29/practical-kohana-hooks-example-phpids/

<strike>http://learn.kohanaphp.com/2008/04/14/5-tips-to-help-you-find-something-youre-looking-for-in-kohana/</strike>

And, of course, Google.

Comment: http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php

Answer (score 17):

I had exactly the same problem! After a few searches I found the Kohaha101.pdf. This guide/tutorial really got me started!

Link:[http://pixelpeter.com/kohana/kohana101.pdf[1](http://pixelpeter.com/kohana/kohana101.pdf)

Good luck and enjoy Kohana!

Comment: Here's another link (non-pdf) http://dev.kohanaframework.org/wiki/kohana2/Kohana101

Answer (score 8):

Since this is bumped anyway:

If you're looking for Kohana 3 beginners tutorials, the ones listed at the bottom of the unoffical  [Wiki](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/) are pretty good.

Comment: Agreed! Those really helped me get started =)

Answer (score 3):

Learning Kohana is a pain. There is some information out there but it's all over the place and Google is your best ally. The support forums are pretty good but it's very much a framework for PHP geeks. It addresses all of the fundamental flaws of PHP and provides a clean MVC design pattern but nothing more.

The advantage of such a minimal approach is that it's lean and lightning fast. When things don't work you will find the need to go through the libraries as sometimes it's easier to understand what methods/properties are available or how they work by looking through the underlying code. It would be nice for somebody to donate some money and for the team to pump it into proper documentation as it's the achilles heel of the whole project.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one link: [Kohana Tutorial](http://learn.kohanaphp.com/tutorials/)
But anyway - just enter word: Kohana tutorial into Google and your question is answered.

Comment: That link you posted is just a collection of tutorials for doing very specific task, and not a beginner's guide.

Answer (score 2):

[Kohana Primer](http://www.google.com/notebook/public/15243151709237300427/BDSaoIgoQv5fS67kj) is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to tell everyone that the Kohana 101 has been transfered to the wiki and it is (and will be) up to date with the current stable versions of the Kohana framework.

[You can find it here.](http://dev.kohanaphp.com/wiki/kohana2/Kohana101)

Comment: link broken (2011-09-06)

Comment: It is really outdated anyhow, see the date this was posted. It is far better to check out the [unofficial resource](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php) for things like this

Comment: Funny, http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php gives me a 403. :-) Assuming you meant http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php ...

Comment: Yep, possibly that got moved too ;)
It was working when I linked it :P

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on to the list! I wrote one a little while back: http://flowdev.tumblr.com/post/1351061705/kohana-tutorial

Most of my blog posts are about Kohana.

Comment: No problem. I know that there is little documentation for begginers out there. I should know, took me months to learn the basics. I am writing a begginers guide to web development and Kohana on and off, I should probably push and try to finish one of them/

Answer (score 0):

I agree. I guess since the transition from 2.x to 3.x, the docs need to be improved. Anyway, I weeded through the basics and brought up a blog article about how to get started fast:

http://voloreport.com/learn-kohana-mvc-php-in-under-an-hour1

The first part that I wrote starts with a discussion about what MVC is, and why Kohana. In Part 2, I go on to explain how to install and use Kohana.

Answer (score 0):

Most recent now is 3.1 - took a little toolin' through the website, but I found this - hope it helps someone:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/

And more specifically for tutorials:
http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/tutorials