# How to start to dev a Web Directory System

Tags: php, kohana

I am planing to build a simple web dictionary system with Kohana 3.

```
categories

. website title;
. website URL;
. website logo;
. website description.
. etc.
```

How to write a professional design specification for my project and 
is there any good tutorial to start?

Appreciated for reading and the replies.

Comment: Think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394175/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The "Kohana Tutorial" pages are pants.
>   Not so much for their content, but for
>   the fact that they have a pretty damn
>   unorganised wordpress blog and finding
>   useful info isn't exactly made easy.
>   What they need is a post/page at
>   learn.kohanaphp.com that lists the
>   most important tutorials, rather than
>   forcing you to wade through the whole
>   blog.
>
> Anyway, rant over, I'd start here:
>
> http://zacklive.com/hello-world-tutorial-for-kohana/15/
>
> Then:
>
> http://learn.kohanaphp.com/2008/03/26/blog-tutorial-1/
>
> http://learn.kohanaphp.com/2008/03/28/blog-tutorial-part-2/
>
> Other articles of interest:
>
> http://www.ninjapenguin.co.uk/blog/2008/06/21/kohana-pagination-tutorial/
>
> http://learn.kohanaphp.com/2008/04/25/using-auto_modeler-to-write-quicker-code/
>
> http://www.ninjapenguin.co.uk/blog/2008/06/29/practical-kohana-hooks-example-phpids/
>
> http://learn.kohanaphp.com/2008/04/14/5-tips-to-help-you-find-something-youre-looking-for-in-kohana/
>
> And, of course, Google.

Comment: @maxedmelon, I am consued with the Kohana2 andKohana3. I plan to installed and start with KO3. I found a lot of tutorials based on Kohana2.X. Thank you.

Comment: So you've copied and pasted this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394175/searching-for-a-kohana-beginners-tutorial-for-php/467326#467326. Wouldn't it be better to link to it and give credit where credit's due ?

Comment: i quoted it :) and the thread is mentioned above. quoted stuff means its copied/quoted.

@Nano HE: Use v3. v3 is LOTS more advanced and has some neat stuff. http://v3.kohanaphp.com/guide/tutorials.urls